# White bike components

Tags: parts, single-speed, cyclocross

I would like to simplify the colors on my bike using white on components above the top-tube (saddle, seatpost, stem, cyclocross brake lever, LED lights, grips).  I am having a hard time finding a white cyclocross brake lever.  I have found them in black and silver and several colors in anodized alum.

Anyone know where I can find white cyclocross brake levers?
White LED light?
White seatpost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Searching on Google, I found plenty white LED lights such as [this one](http://www.mec.ca/product/5034-783/mec-galaxy-dual-usb-redwhite-led-bike-light/).  The problem might be that color is not a good criteria for selecting bike lights. The most important factors being reliability, light output, and battery life.  You should first choose a light that meets those criteria before worrying about color. Most of the high end stuff I see is either black or silver. Perhaps silver could be a good compromise.

As far as seat posts go. Just go a Google Image Search for white seat post and you'll find many different models from high quality manufacturers. For brake levers, are you asking about drop bar levers or interrupter levers? You can get replacement brake hoods in white, but I don't think I've seen any drop bar or interrupter levers that are white. Here again, you may want to use silver as a compromise.

The other option being get unpainted aluminium and paint it yourself.  I'm not sure how good of a result this would get.

Comment: The painting option will likely look sloppy if done at home [and painting aluminum is tricky to begin with]. However, steel things can probably be nicely powdercoated if you're willing to put in the money.

Comment: Thanks Batman, for the tips on alum and steel.  Kibbee, I agree that color is not a good criteria for lights.  It's also not a good criteria for the brake levers.  I was hoping there was a special edition from White Ind or Paul Comp

Comment: If it is dark enough for lighting, a light with a raw aluminium casing will look white enough.

Answer (score 0):

A light  [Serfas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007VG2WP2)

[maybe white](https://www.serfas.com/products/view/152/referer:products%7Cindex%7Clights%7Cheadlights%7Cpage:3)

I have a 3T Dorilo seatpost that is white with some red.